# How to detect the difference between a change made by a user and a change made programmatically?

Tags: javascript, triggers, onchange

I have an onChange event handler that is being triggered twice; once for a change made by a user, and a second time for a change made programmatically as a result from the original user's change. The event should only be triggered once, for the former. How do you discern between a changed made by a user and one by a script?

Comment: And you're not using jQuery, this is in plain javascript? You should post some relevant code to show us the event handler and how it's triggered, maybe set up a fiddle. As a general rule you can't distiguish a triggered event and a user event.

Comment: One trick may be to turn off the event for the widget while handling the event, then turn it back on when done. We may be able to help more if you post an example of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just change the value with `el.value = x`, the `change` event is not triggered. For example, this [won't log anything to the console](http://jsfiddle.net/a5A2s/):

```
var el = document.getElementById('el')
el.onchange = function(){
    console.log('changed');
};
el.value = 'asasassasa';
```

So, if you're seeing it's being triggered twice, it's either because:

- You're manually triggering it with `el.onchange()`. In this case, just remove the this call.

Or:

- The event handler is bound to the element more than once. You have to locate where that's happening.

Answer (score 0):

One good approach to catch such issues and sometimes work around them is to always check the older value with the present value in the onchange handler.

```
function onChange_handler(e){
  if(this.old_value==this.value){
        return; // no change detected - check why was it called twice.
  }
  this.old_value=this.value;
  // the real change handling code
}
```